# rails to_json remove quote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, net-http

I am working the the LogMeIn Central API and in the body of my request I need to send some Json. I have this:

```
  host_ids = LmiHost.all.collect {|lmi| lmi.host_id}.join ', '
  create_servicetag_report_request.body = {hostIds: host_ids, fields: 'ServiceTag'}.to_json
```

This turns the body into

> {\"hostIds\":\"5888, 6225, 214752\",\"fields\":\"ServiceTag\"}

how can i remove the

> \"

from this section:

> \"5888, 6225, 214752\"

it is not suppose to have quotes around it.

I am using Ruby on Rails

Comment: JSON strings are supposed to be wrapped by double-quotes - are you sure the API is expecting JSON, as opposed to a comma-separated list of IDs?

Comment: positive, see here http://developer.logmein.com/api/hostactions/#system-inventory

Comment: Then remove the `join` from line 1 and you are good to go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `to_json` adds the `\"` (escaped quotations) is because it is converting hostIds as a string. In your rails console try this to see the difference.

```
{"hostids":[0,1,2,3]}.to_json
=> "{\"hostids\":[0,1,2,3]}"

{"hostids":"[0,1,2,3]"}.to_json
=> "{\"hostids\":\"[0,1,2,3]\"}"
```

This can be seen another way by trying:  `puts [1,2,3,4]` vs `puts "[1,2,3,4]"`

Ultimately I would refer to the LMI Central API to figure out exactly how multiple hostIds can be sent.

Comment: `host_ids` is a string because the OP explicitly made it one. using `join ', '`

Comment: Right, and this is why it is displaying as such. If OP wants valid json, a list of ids can only be a comma separated string or an array/array of hashes

Comment: He just added the link to their API Doc it says: "hostIds": [<id1>, <id2>, ...], so it should be an Array not a String.

Comment: Yeah I commented on it. I was more or less mentioning your phrasing of *"It looks like hostIds is a string."*

Comment: It looks exactly like it :)

Comment: thanks guys, that makes sense. going to test it as a array in a few minutes and ill post back

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JSON.parse(create_servicetag_report_request.body[:hostIds])` to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `join` part from this line:

```
host_ids = LmiHost.all.collect { |lmi| lmi.host_id }.join ', '
```

`join` joins your array of ids into a comma separated string. This doesn't seems to be what you want.

Btw. you can shorten `.collect { |lmi| lmi.host_id }` to `map(&:host_id)`:

```
create_servicetag_report_request.body = {
  hostIds: LmiHost.all.map(&:host_id), 
  fields:  'ServiceTag'
}.to_json
```